# Is it good to add other products in a single product page?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata, structured-data

By following schema.org web page, I designed a single product page on a website for my client. I've followed most of the schema required to enlist a single product on a single product page.

My question is, can I mention other products on the same single product page under category anything close "You may also like"?

If so, should I add schema to those products too?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In general: the more structured data, the better.

Schema.org defines properties for this purpose:

- [`isRelatedTo`](http://schema.org/isRelatedTo) for a "somehow related" `Product`
- [`isSimilarTo`](http://schema.org/isSimilarTo) for a "functionally similar" `Product`

(And for special cases, [`isAccessoryOrSparePartFor`](http://schema.org/isAccessoryOrSparePartFor) and [`isConsumableFor`](http://schema.org/isConsumableFor).)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you should open it to more products. By doing so it allows the users to look at a product and then possible find stuff that they may also like. Also the user is more likely to see more products by doing so there for you show more of the product increasing sales.

Comment: I know that it is good for user experience. But there are no privileges to add 2 or more products in a single product page in schema.org

Comment: Can you send me a jsfiddle.net of your current piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you mean is "Related Product" or "Bundle Promo" feature? for me is a good trick to attract more customer attention to view or bought another product on the same transaction :)